# Beamed note with unfilled heads — What is this?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

In the 1905 [incidental score to *Peter Pan*](https://archive.org/details/musictojmbarrie00barrgoog) by John Crook (1852–1922), there’s a notation I’m unfamiliar with: double-beamed notes with unfilled heads. (See the first four bars of the score below.)

In context they appear to be some variant of the quarter note, but is there something about this form I need to know? If I reproduce this score, will any information be lost if I use standard quarter notes (♩) instead?

[image: John Crook’s score, illustrating the unfamiliar notation]

Comment: Note that the second half of bar 1 will be played the same as the first half. After which the L.H moves into the top stave, taking the lower notes. The rhythm of bar 1 continues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are tremolos. The convention is that the notes that are beamed together are alternated using the value of the beam (that means that F♯ and D that start the 2nd bar in the top voice would be alternated as 16th notes, for instance), and the note heads reflect the length of time to be filled, in this case a half note for each notated tremolo group.

Comment: I am confused by your answer.  I am seeing E and G# followed by B and D.  Second, do you trem between the two intervals or the two notes within the interval?

Answer (score 14):

No, you can't substitute quarter notes. This notation indicates that the player should continue alternating between the two pitches in a sixteenth-note rhythm. Look at the first bar: although the first two beats are written as 8 sixteenths and the second two beats are the unfilled beamed noteheads, the second half of the measure should sound identical to the first half. It's just a common shorthand that saves some ink during repetitive passages. Look for instance in the first movement of Beethoven's Grande Sonata Pathetique, you'll see many examples.

Comment: Is there a name for this technique?

Comment: Yeah, I think "measured tremolo" is the best phrase to describe it. If it were three beams then it would be unmeasured, meaning as fast as possible, but one or two beams is a shorthand for eighth or sixteenth notes alternating.

Comment: @PatMuchmore: Is three beams necessarily "unmeasured", or would that depend upon whether the piece used 32nd notes elsewhere and was at a tempo where 32nd notes would be plausible?  I would expect that an editor who intended 32nd notes would probably want to include a footnote specifying that, but would there be anything "incorrect" about such notation?

Comment: @supercat, Great question. Definitely possible for it to mean 32nd notes if the piece is quite slow or, as you say, already has been using 32nds regularly. In that case I'd use 4 for unmeasured. The footnote isn't a bad idea, even though most would probably know just from context. Better safe than sorry if it's an important distinction...

Answer (score 3):

> In context they appear to be some variant of the quarter note

The other answers are right: those are tremolos. But you're not completely off the mark, either:  there *is* other music where, indeed, eights with open noteheads are a notation for quarter notes, and can be beamed: in Couperin's *Goûts Réunis* one finds for example:

[image]

Comment: Also for instance in Charpentier's [O salutaris](http://hz.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/a/a8/IMSLP178791-PMLP313605-osalutaris.pdf)

Comment: So called "void" or "white" 3/2 notation is a holdover from mensural notation, but composers like Couperin and Charpentier used "ordinary" notation as well.  Some printers even [requested](http://tenor2016.tenor-conference.org/papers/10_Zitellini_tenor2016.pdf)  separate moveable type to be able to typeset it. But why? One hypothesis is that it denotes a _slow_ 3/2 (so a _sesquialtera_ rather than a _tripla_ proportion)

Comment: In addition, I suppose that the time signature "2/3" should be "3/2" in the picture?

Comment: Yes, this is usually corrected in modern editions. In contrast to "void" notation, which was used by many more composers, these inverted time signatures seem to be peculiar to Couperin. He has a few more of them in his _Pièces de Clavecin_, like an 8/3 in _les Baccanales_ , or an 8/4 instead of a 4/8 in _l' Ausoniène_. I don't know of any good explanation for them.